# How to Find Orbits and Stabilizers

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, dihedral-groups, orbit-stabilizer

The question is:

Let $S$ denote the set of possible black-or-white colorings of the edges of an equilateral triangle. The triangle's symmetry group $D_6$ acts naturally on $S$.

**(a)** How many orbits are there?

**(b)** By listing an element from each orbit show there are 10 orbits if three colors were used.

So I have sort of done the first part but my answers are contradicting when I list out the orbits vs when I used the formula

$$|D_6| = |\operatorname{Stab}(S)| \cdot|\operatorname{Orb}(S)|$$

And I am also stuck in the second part. Any help is appreciated :)

[image: This is a photo of my workings]

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: This looks like a situation suited for what is usually called [Burnside's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you are using is incorrect. It is not used for the whole set, but for one element only
$$\forall\ s\in S,\lvert D_6\rvert=\lvert\text{Stab}(s)\rvert\cdot\lvert\text{Orb}(s)\rvert$$

That's the problem you are having and also $\lvert\text{Orb}(s)\rvert$ is not the number of orbits, but the size of the orbit of $s$.

Knowing that the stabilizers must be subgroups and knowing that the non trivial subgroups of $D_6\cong S_3$ are $C_2,C_3$ we can count the orbits.

- $\text{Stab}(s)\cong D_6$, then all sides must have the same colour.
- $\text{Stab}(s)\cong C_3$, it is impossible, all sides must have the same colour, but that means that $\text{Stab}(s)\cong D_6$.
- $\text{Stab}(s)\cong C_2$, then two sides must have the same colour.
- $\text{Stab}(s)\cong\{e\}$, then all sides must have different colour.

Then counting all elements

| Stabilizer | Size of orbit | 2 colours | 3 colours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $D_6$ | $1$ | $2$ | $3$ |
| $C_2$ | $3$ | $2\cdot1\cdot{3\choose2}=6$ | $3\cdot2\cdot{3\choose2}=18$ |
| $\{e\}$ | $6$ | $0$ | $3\cdot2\cdot1=6$ |
| Total |  | $2^3=8$ | $3^3=27$ |

And counting all orbits, by dividing the number of elements by the size of the orbit

| Stabilizer | 2 colours | 3 colours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $D_6$ | $2$ | $3$ |
| $C_2$ | $2$ | $6$ |
| $\{e\}$ | $0$ | $1$ |
| Total | $4$ | $10$ |

So for 3 colours you can list (using red, blue and green): RRR, BBB, GGG, RRB, RRG, BBR, BBG, GGR, GGB, RGB.

Comment: So I get the first part, thank you for correcting my misunderstanding! However, I don't understand the intuitive meaning of number of orbits, why is it number of elements that have that orbit/ size of the orbit? I feel like this is from the orbit-counting formula but can link the two. Thank you

Comment: @palragve_23 Every element can only be in one orbit, so the number of elements in orbits of the same type must be, number of orbits times size of the orbit. Solving for the number of orbits you get the  number of orbits. Then you must add all different types of orbits

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!